# Getting new coordinate position after AutoCad/WPF/SVG Transform

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, matrix-multiplication, autocad

I'm trying to retrieve and save a (x,y) position for later reference in a 2D model in SVG. The original model is in Autocad and using a software tool to convert to WPF which gets converted again to SVG like this.

```
var model = GetModel();
var Matrix4DTransform = Matrix.Identity
wpfGraphics.CreateFrameworkElements(model, Matrix4DTransform);
```

Works now but is upside down so I use this transform instead

```
var ModelWidth = bounds.Delta.X;
var ModelHeight = bounds.Delta.Y;

Matrix4DTransform= DxfUtil.GetScaleTransform(
   bounds.Corner1,
   bounds.Corner2,
   bounds.Center,
   new Point3D(0, ModelHeight, 0d),
   new Point3D(ModelWidth, 0, 0d),
   new Point3D(ModelWidth / 2d, ModelHeight /2 , 0d)
);

wpfGraphics.CreateFrameworkElements(model, Matrix4DTransform);
```

Now it is right side up and if drawn on a canvas, the width and height is the same as the model. All is well so far.

Now converting to SVG

```
StringBuilder svg = new StringBuilder();
svg.AppendLine("<svg width='{0}' height='{1}'>", ModelWidth, ModelHeight);
svg.AppendLine("<g id='main'>");

foreach(FrameworkElement f in wpfGraphics.FrameworkElements)
{
    svg.AppendLine(string.Format("<path data='{0}'>", f.Data)); 

}
svg.AppendLine("</g>");
svg.AppendLine("</svg>");
```

All is still well, SVG Doc is now identical to original model, but now a point in the original model (x,y) is different than a point in the SVG doc.. the points seems to be reversed even thought he model is the exact same dimensions.

The goal is to have a point saved into a database, shown on the model, but then the user can change that point, which would be saved back to the database. Right now the points are not the same.